# How to add text or image to customized listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am trying to add a array of string and an image to my list view. I managed to custimize each line in the listview but now I cant see the text in each line in the list view. I also want to add an image to each line in the list view. I think I need to use a diffrent adapter..

Code:

```
 todoItems.add(redString);
   todoItems.add(blueString);
   todoItems.add(yellowString);
 final ArrayAdapter<String> aa  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listviewitem,todoItems);
  mylistListView.setAdapter(aa);
```

listviewitem XML:

```
<com.todo.ListViewItem
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textColor="@color/notepad_text"
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
>
```

Comment: Refer the below link..... http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listsactivity_layout

Comment: What you say about this example? [Android ListView examples](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-%E2%80%93-listview-%E2%80%93-5-%E2%80%93-optimized-custom-listview/)

Answer (score 0):

i recomend you to use layout inflaters in your list. here is an example.

1)main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="1">


  <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"     
   android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"   
   android:layout_height="330dp" 
   android:layout_weight="0.48"></ListView>
   </LinearLayout>
```

2) create a layout named 'list.xml' that includes a text and an image as you wish to have in your list.

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    try{
mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    getList();


    }catch(Exception e){

    }


private void getList(final ArrayList<Object> asdf) {


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Object>(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.list, asdf) {

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {

             View row;

            if (null == convertView) {
                row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
            } else {
                row = convertView;
            }

            TextView text1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            ImageView im = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image1);

            row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });

            return row;
        }

    });

}
```